# Images displayed differently on testflight than iphone 6 device during development

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

Iam facing a strange issue, during development of react native app using macbook and real iphone6 device, the images displayed correctly, then when i do package the application and upload to test flight, if i download the test flight version on the same iphone6 that i used in development the images displayed differently,
here are some screen shots when i download the app from testflight
[image]

[image: from test flight]

while during development using the same exact device, the same screens are displayed like this
[image: development]

[image: 2]